# Autofilter Returns no rows but so the visible range is nothing but the Filtered Visible Range is not nothing

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

So this is the relevant part of the code:

```
i = Feuil1.Cells.Rows.count

i = Feuil1.Cells(i, 1).End(xlUp).Row
j = Feuil1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
HelpAddress = Feuil1.Cells(i, j).Address

Set Table = Feuil1.ListObjects("FiltersTable")

HelpArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Table.ListColumns("Rubriques").DataBodyRange)
HelpArr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Table.ListColumns("Departements").DataBodyRange)
HelpArr = UniqueNoEmpty(HelpArr)
HelpArr2 = UniqueNoEmpty(HelpArr2)

For i = LBound(HelpArr2) To UBound(HelpArr2)
    HelpArr2(i) = CStr(HelpArr2(i)) & "*"
Next i

FilterArray2 = Array("*@*")

Set Wbk = Workbooks.Add
Set Ws = Wbk.Worksheets(1)
Feuil1.Activate
Feuil1.Range("A1" & ":" & Feuil1.Cells(1, j).Address).Copy
Ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For Each Rubrique In HelpArr
    
    FilterArray = Array(Rubrique & "*")
    
    With Feuil1
        On Error Resume Next
        .ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0
'        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=11
        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=FilterArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=FilterArray2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
'        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=FilterArray3, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Operator:=xlOr
    End With
    
    For i = LBound(HelpArr2) To UBound(HelpArr2)
        
        Feuil1.Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4
        Feuil1.Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=HelpArr2(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Set FilteredRng = Feuil1.Range("A2" & ":" & HelpAddress).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
        If Not FilteredRng Is Nothing Then
            FilteredRng.Copy
            Set HelpRng = Ws.Cells(Ws.Cells.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
            Do While HelpRng.Value <> ""
                Set HelpRng = HelpRng.Offset(1, 0)
            Loop
            Ws.Range(HelpRng.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        
    Next i
    
Next Rubrique
```

The first line in Feuil1 is the row with the headers with filters.

The thing is that when the Criteria1 gives no rows as result, and so the only visible row is the row with the filters, in that case the visible range is nothing BUT `FilteredRng is Nothing` gives False as result because for some reason FilteredRng is actually the first row with the filters.

I can't understand how this happens because the first row was not part of the range to begin with.

Furthermore it prevents me from catching the error using `if FilteredRng is Nothing then`

Now the workaround for this is `if FilteredRng.rows.count = 1 and FilteredRng.row=1 then` but still I'd like to be able to catch the error by comparing with Nothing as the filter row / header row might change rows in different cases... and I have pre-built functions and subs that are for general case use where I compare to Nothing.

If anyone knows what's going on here or how to catch the 'No cells found' error I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE:**

After updating the code following Rory's comments this is how the code looks like now:

```
On Error Resume Next
Feuil1.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

i = Feuil1.Cells.Rows.count

i = Feuil1.Cells(i, 1).End(xlUp).Row
j = Feuil1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
HelpAddress = Feuil1.Cells(i, j).Address

Set Wbk = Workbooks.Add
Set Ws = Wbk.Worksheets(1)
Feuil1.Activate
Feuil1.Range("A1:" & Feuil1.Cells(1, j).Address).Copy
Ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Set Table = Feuil1.ListObjects("FiltersTable")

HelpArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Table.ListColumns("Rubriques").DataBodyRange)
HelpArr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Table.ListColumns("Departements").DataBodyRange)
HelpArr = UniqueNoEmpty(HelpArr)
HelpArr2 = UniqueNoEmpty(HelpArr2)

For i = LBound(HelpArr2) To UBound(HelpArr2)
    HelpArr2(i) = CStr(HelpArr2(i)) & "*"
Next i

FilterArray2 = Array("*@*")

For Each Rubrique In HelpArr
    
    FilterArray = Array(Rubrique & "*")
    
    With Feuil1
        On Error Resume Next
        .ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0
'        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=11
        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=FilterArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=FilterArray2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
'        .Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=FilterArray3, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Operator:=xlOr
    End With
    
    For i = LBound(HelpArr2) To UBound(HelpArr2)
        
        Set FilteredRng = Nothing
        Feuil1.Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4
        Feuil1.Range("A1" & ":" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=HelpArr2(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FilteredRng = Feuil1.Range("A2" & ":" & HelpAddress).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not FilteredRng Is Nothing Then
'        If FilteredRng.Rows.count = 1 And FilteredRng.Row = 1 Then
            FilteredRng.Copy
            Set HelpRng = Ws.Cells(Ws.Cells.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
            Do While HelpRng.Value <> ""
                Set HelpRng = HelpRng.Offset(1, 0)
            Loop
            Ws.Range(HelpRng.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        
    Next i
    
Next Rubrique
```

Comment: If you apply `SpecialCells` to one cell, it applies to the whole sheet.

Comment: I'm not applying SpecialCells to any cell, I'm using the property SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to return the range of visible cells only , it doesn't apply any filters to the page or cells.

Comment: Yes, you are, and if HelpAddress is "A2", you are applying it to a singe cell range, which has the same effect as applying it to the entire used range of the sheet, which is why you get the header row included.

Comment: @Rory if I use the SpecialCells method while getting result rows then FilteredRng returns the visible rows without including the header row, which is also visible, so if it is the way you say , that by using the SpecialCells method I apply the corresponding filter to the entire page, why would it return the header row as result (in the case there were no result rows) when the header row wasn't part of the FilteredRng??

Comment: Again, if the range whose SpecialCells property you use is only **one cell**, then it is as if you apply it to the entire usedrange of the sheet. Looking at the code again, that seems unlikely **but** if `i` is `1` (since you don't clear the filter on the sheet before calculating that), then `Range("A2" & ":" & HelpAddress)` will include row 1.

Comment: @Rory , ok so this time I cleared the filter before calculating , and HelpAddress = "$N$300" , do you agree with me that we're not talking about 1 cell and also that row 1 is not included in the range? I'm still getting the same result... and the returned range when there are no result rows is actually the fisrt row, which was never included in the range... also while looking at the properties of FilteredRng even though it returns somehow the first row, it also gives the error 'No cells found'

Comment: In that case, the only way I can see you getting row 1 included is if you set `FilteredRng` somewhere else previously - if `SpecialCells` fails, it will not return `Nothing`, it just errors out so the range variable will be whatever it was set to previously.

Comment: @Rory So I set 'set FilteredRng = Nothing' at the start of the loop. Now the returned Range IS Nothing. However the curious thing about this is that in this specific case , before ,when I didn't set FilteredRng to Nothing, on the first run through the loop (so that FilteredRng was not initialized yet) I had no result rows, and FilteredRng would have the 'No cells found' error on the porperties but would still return the first row  even though it wasn't initialized yet. Initializing it to nothing prevents this from happening.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "would still return the first row"? Are you sure you hadn't set it earlier in the code?

Comment: @Rory , yeah Rory I am completely sure it wasn't set before, If you want I'll show you the entire code so you can see for yourself. That apart , I wrote an answer based on your comments, the credit should go to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for this answer should go to Rory as it was his comments that provided the solution

So the answer to this was setting the range to nothing , applying the desired filters and then set the range using the SpecialCells properties.

```
        Set FilteredRng = Nothing
        Feuil1.Range("A1:" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4
        Feuil1.Range("A1:" & HelpAddress).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=HelpArr2(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FilteredRng = Feuil1.Range("A2:" & HelpAddress).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not FilteredRng Is Nothing Then
            'Code here
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

### Reference AutoFilter Visible Cells

- Here's an example of how to tackle this.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFilterExample()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove previous
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Table Range
    Dim dtrg As Range ' Data Range (refernce before the 'AutoFilter')
    Set dtrg = trg.Resize(trg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    trg.AutoFilter 1, "Yes"
    
    Dim vrg As Range ' Visible Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set vrg = dtrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' use the data range ('dtrg')
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If Not vrg Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print vrg.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nope"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try your solution and give you feedback, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

With a table the header row and databody (excluding header) ranges are available as properties of the table.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject
    Dim wbOut As Workbook, wsOut As Worksheet, rowOut As Long
    Dim colRub As ListColumn, colDept As ListColumn
    Dim arRub, arDept, i As Long
    
    Set ws = Sheet1 ' or Feuil1
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    ' get unique rubriques and departements
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("FiltersTable")
    With tbl
        Set colRub = .ListColumns("Rubriques")
        arRub = UniqueNoEmpty(wsf.Transpose(colRub.DataBodyRange))
    
        Set colDept = .ListColumns("Departements")
        arDept = UniqueNoEmpty(wsf.Transpose(colDept.DataBodyRange))
    End With
    
    ' create workbook for reults
    Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsOut = wbOut.Worksheets(1)
    tbl.HeaderRowRange.Copy wsOut.Range("A1")
    rowOut = 1
      
    Dim rubrique, dept, rngFiltered As Range
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With tbl
        For Each rubrique In arRub
       
             ' apply rubrique filter
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=colRub.Index, Criteria1:=rubrique & "*"
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="*@*"
        
            For Each dept In arDept
                
                 ' apply department filter
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=colDept.Index, Criteria1:=dept & "*"
                    
                ' copy filtered data if any
                Set rngFiltered = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rngFiltered = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If rngFiltered Is Nothing Then
                    'Debug.Print "No data for ", rubrique, dept
                Else
                    rngFiltered.Copy
                    wsOut.Range("A" & rowOut + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    rowOut = wsOut.Cells(wsOut.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                End If
            
            Next
        Next
        .Range.AutoFilter
    End With
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox rowOut & " rows copied to " & wbOut.Name

End Sub

Function UniqueNoEmpty(ar)
    Dim d, e: Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each e In ar
        If Len(e) > 0 Then d(CStr(e)) = 1
    Next
    UniqueNoEmpty = d.keys
End Function
```